# Regex for match numbers , hypen and special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have to validate below with the given condition

```
com.android.123foo
```

following conditions should be applied

1. Numbers shouldn't be allowed after the last dot (ex. `"com.android.123foo"`)

   **NOTE**: Numbers can be allowed middle or end of the string (ex. `com.android.foo123 or com.adnroid.fo0123news`)
2. special characters and hyphen should not be allowed over the entire string (ex `com.android.123foo`)

Kindly help.

Comment: after the last dot, I understand?

Comment: Yes after the last dot only @fedorqui

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which dot you are asking about the answer will change, but perhaps you are after something like this:
for after first dot

```
"com.iphones22tore.123foo".match /^.*\.[a-zA-Z.]*$/
=> nil
"com.iphonestore.foo".match /^.*\.[a-zA-Z.]*$/
=> #<MatchData "com.iphonestore.foo">
```

If you mean after the final dot then change the regex to:

```
.match /^.*\..*\.[a-zA-Z.]*$/
```

instead of creating a regex for a blacklist after the dot for what isnt allowed, this just simply defines what IS allowed after the dot.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Updated my question, Kindly take a look at it.